# in objective-c initializing an object and giving it an instance name

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, oop, cocos2d-iphone

in cocos2d-iphone I have a CCLayer class called GameScene

I want to use this class from another class however I dont know the name of the instance of the GameScene class

I initialized an instance of GameScene class as follows

```
  -(id) init {
        if ((self = [super init])) {
```

however this will not give me the name of the instance

I read in documentation that  a method called initWithName can be used so I tried something like this but it does not work it gives me warning:

```
       In function '-[GameScene init]':
       warning: 'CCLayer' may not respond to '-initWithName:'
```

the code I tried is

```
  -(id) init {
       if ((self = [super initWithName:"gamescene"])) {
```

I will need only one instance of this class through the game but I cant catch a handler of that instance so I can use it from other classes?

any Idea

Many Thanks

---

**update:**

Hello

I am going to update the code to let you know that I have tried your solution but it dosnot seem to work yet

in the MyAppDelegate.h I have this lines of code:

firstly I have defined the app delegate to share it with other classes

MyAppDelegate.h

```
    #define AD  (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

and in the MyAppDelegate.m I have the following code:

```
gs  = [[GameScene alloc] init];//this is the gamescene
sc = [gs scene]; //this calls the method -(id)(scene)
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene: sc]; //runwithscene
```

now when I tried to use the gs within other class -for example player.m class-

player.m

```
GameScene* gs = [AD gs]; //retrieving the instance from appdelegate
[gs updateScoreByAmount:5];/calling the method "updateScoreByAmount"
```

the results , guess what happens?

the program runs without errors however gs instance seems to be different than the one which is run by the appdelegate since this method "updateScoreByAmount" does not affect the scene which run by the runWithScene in the appdelegate

any idea?

Many Thanks to all those who have tried to help

Comment: This is a very confusing question.  Objects do not inherently have a name.  It's difficult to determine what you are trying to do and what kind of trouble you are encountering in doing it.

Comment: try `if ((self = [super initWithName:@"gamescene"])) `

Comment: @Ryan, simply I want to access methods of the gamescene class from another class?

Comment: @vikingosegundo: does not work unfortunately, thanks

Comment: If you are confused how to refer to an object after you have created it, you should refer to darren's answer, below.  Objective-C works like every other C-based language, in that an object is not accessed via an inherent name, given at time of instantiation, but via variable references to the object, as in darren's example.

Comment: @Ryan: thanks, I just updated the question please have a look

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, you need a reference to an instance of the GameScene class?  If that is the case, it depends how the object is created.  You probably are creating the instance from some controller class and it would look something like:

```
GameScene *gameScene = [[GameScene alloc] init];
```

Here, gameScene would be the reference to the instance you need.

Comment: I dont know where does the instance created since this is cocos2d template, the only place which menstioned GameScene is in the app-delegate and it is this line [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene: [GameScene scene]];

Comment: that's it then. To get a reference you would have something like id myObj = [GameScene scene].  In your code you have [GameScene scene] as a parameter to some other method. If you want a reference to it, you need to store that in a variable (myObj in this case).

Comment: thats the question I couldn't fint anyway to store that in a variable???? I am thinking about using singleton but I have to read more about it first,thanks

Comment: ahmed, the line [GameScene scene] is returning an autoreleased game scene pointer that you can keep, the same as if you called [NSString stringWithString:@"Hello"] and kept it in a retained pointer.  In this case you can create a variable in your app delegate to hold your game scene.

Comment: @slycrel: thanks, I just updated the question please have a look

Answer (score 0):

ahmed,

Instead of storing a pointer to your top level scene, you can do this to get access to it:

```
GameScene* myScene = (GameScene*)[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene];
```

CCDirector is a singleton, and it knows what scene it's currently running, so you don't need to keep a pointer to it, you can use the above way of getting to it when you need it.

Because GameScene is a child of CCScene your running scene will be your GameScene object.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, what I want is to share the instance of the class "GameScene" not the instance of the "CCScene", but your code should help me in other situations thank you

Comment: ahmed, GameScene is a CCScene child correct?  I will update the above code to reflect that.